# get last but one terminal/console command

Tags: linux, bash

How I can easily access last but one terminal/console command or N command ago?

Example:
$history | tail
1840  echo last but one command
1841  echo last command
1842  history | tail

I know about `!!` or `!$` but it will catch only the last command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know the `!!` gives you the access to the last command. The exclamation mark also allows for the history access - like so:

```
$ history |tail -3
  954  sudo pacman -Syu
  955  ping -c 2 luna.localdomain 
  956  history |tail -3
$ !955
ping -c 2 luna.localdomain
64 bytes from luna.localdomain (192.168.178.201): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.73 ms
64 bytes from luna.localdomain (192.168.178.201): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.24 ms
--- luna.localdomain ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.729/1.982/2.235/0.253 ms
$
```

That would be the preferable way of accessing the *n*-th command in the history. The negative *n* values allow for backwards history access; for instance the second last command can be accessed via `!-2`;

```
$ !-2
history |tail -3
  954  sudo pacman -Syu
  955  ping -c 2 luna.localdomain
  956  history |tail -3
$
```